# PHP double line break between arrays in while loop

Tags: php, arrays

Im stuck on an issue I just cant solve. Ive thought about how, looked it up, and have not yielded any results.

Im trying to use an array in an email, and I need a double line break between them.

Im creating two arrays from within a mysql query results loop like so:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $updated_email_array['Clinic']=$row['clinic_name'];
        $updated_email_array['Email_Credits_To_Add']=$row['email_allotment'];
        $updated_email_array['SMS_Credits_To_Add']=$row['sms_allotment'];
        $updated_email_array['Email_Credits_Rolling_Over']=$row['$email_left'];
        $display_email_array[] = $updated_email_array;
}
```

Im then parsing out the values and adding them to a variable to be nested in an email, like so:

```
$intouch_credit_refill_message = "Credit Refill Report\n\n";
foreach ($display_email_array as $each_member) { 
    while (list($key, $value) = each ($each_member)) { 

        $intouch_credit_refill_message .= "$key: $value\n"; 

    } 

}
```

Lastly, im sending $intouch_credit_refill_message in an email

```
mail($email address,"Credit Refill Record",$intouch_credit_refill_message,"From: email@address.com");
```

This gives me:

```
Credit Refill Report

Clinic: Royal York Animal Hospital
Email_Credits_To_Add: 5000
SMS_Credits_To_Add: 500
Email_Credits_Rolling_Over: 100200
Smail_Credits_Rolling_Over: 10050
New_Email_Credit_Allotment: 105200
New_SMS_Credit_Allotment: 10550
Clinic: Jason's Test Clinic
Email_Credits_To_Add: 5000
SMS_Credits_To_Add: 500
Email_Credits_Rolling_Over: 75000
Smail_Credits_Rolling_Over: 7500
New_Email_Credit_Allotment: 80000
New_SMS_Credit_Allotment: 8000
```

But I Need:

```
Credit Refill Report

Clinic: Royal York Animal Hospital
Email_Credits_To_Add: 5000
SMS_Credits_To_Add: 500
Email_Credits_Rolling_Over: 100200
Smail_Credits_Rolling_Over: 10050
New_Email_Credit_Allotment: 105200
New_SMS_Credit_Allotment: 10550

Clinic: Jason's Test Clinic
Email_Credits_To_Add: 5000
SMS_Credits_To_Add: 500
Email_Credits_Rolling_Over: 75000
Smail_Credits_Rolling_Over: 7500
New_Email_Credit_Allotment: 80000
New_SMS_Credit_Allotment: 8000
```

I cant figure out how to add a break like that between the arrays in the loop where they are added to the email line.

Thank you for any help you might give.

Comment: why don't you just put break before Clinic and single break after heading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another new line in your foreach loop like this:

```
foreach ($display_email_array as $each_member) { 
    while (list($key, $value) = each ($each_member)) { 

        $intouch_credit_refill_message .= "$key: $value\n"; 

    } 

    $intouch_credit_refill_message .= "\n";

}
```

Comment: I kept trying to force it inside the while loop... Its very obvious after you gave your answer that this is what I should have done.

Answer (score 0):

At any-time in PHP if you need a line break or a tab just do this

```
echo "\r\n";

echo "\t";
```

You can also use `PHP_EOL` when you want a new line, and you want to be cross-platform.

### php reference:

PHP_EOL (string)
    The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform. Available since PHP 5.0.2